# Can't get nodetime run properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation, monitoring

I'm trying to get this [nodetime](http://nodetime.com/docs) running, but seems there's some prblems I can't figur out. I did exactly as the guide say, So i supposed to get following:

> After your start your application, a link of the form https://nodetime.com/[session_id] will be printed to the console, where the session will be your unique id for accessing the profiler server

It end the console didn't display any session id link, only this:

`23 Aug 13:32:23 - Nodetime: profiler resumed for 180 seconds`

Maybe any of you guys has experienced same issue? Looking for fixes! Thanks, in advance!

Below is what i got after nodetime installation, i got some Python error, but still seems lika a successful installation...

```
npm WARN package.json application-name@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm WARN package.json jade@0.26.3 No README.md file found!
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/nodetime
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/nodetime
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/nodetime/-/nodetime-0.4.5.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/nodetime/-/nodetime-0.4.5.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request/2.10.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/v8tools
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/timekit
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request/2.10.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.10.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/v8tools
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/v8tools/-/v8tools-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/timekit
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/timekit/-/timekit-0.1.9.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/v8tools/-/v8tools-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.10.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/timekit/-/timekit-0.1.9.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

> timekit@0.1.9 install C:\Users\TJIA\Desktop\Sommarjobb\Extrauppgifter\demo\nod
e_modules\nodetime\node_modules\timekit
> node-gyp rebuild


> v8tools@0.1.1 install C:\Users\TJIA\Desktop\Sommarjobb\Extrauppgifter\demo\nod
e_modules\nodetime\node_modules\v8tools
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\TJIA\Desktop\Sommarjobb\Extrauppgifter\demo\node_modules\nodetime\node_
modules\timekit>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gy
p-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

C:\Users\TJIA\Desktop\Sommarjobb\Extrauppgifter\demo\node_modules\nodetime\node_
modules\v8tools>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gy
p-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\n
pm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:110:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_module
s\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:74:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
gyp gypERR!  System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
ERR! gyp configure errorERR!
 command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_module
s\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\TJIA\Desktop\Sommarjobb\Extrauppgifter\demo\node_modules\n
odetime\node_modules\timekit
gypgyp  ERR! node -v v0.8.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.6.3
gyp ERR! not ok
ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON
env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\n
pm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:110:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_module
s\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:74:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\nod
e_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\TJIA\Desktop\Sommarjobb\Extrauppgifter\demo\node_modules\n
odetime\node_modules\v8tools
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.6.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing timekit@0.1.9
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing v8tools@0.1.1
nodetime@0.4.5 node_modules\nodetime
+-- request@2.10.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm fails to install optional dependencies of nodetime: timekit and v8tools (C bindings), and the reason is correctly mentioned in previous answer (python missing). Although it should be usable even without those modules (a few features will not function though, e.g. CPU and heap profiling).

If your initialization looks like this `require('nodetime').profile()`, i.e. profile() call without any arguments, then something is wrong besides the failed optional dependencies. Use debug flag to see what's wrong: `require('nodetime').profile({debug: true})`. Could be network related, etc.

If you're using Nodetime Pro, and included your account key and app name in profile call, i.e. `require('nodetime').profile({accountKey: '...', appName: '...'})`, then your application should appear on your apps page after logging in to nodetime.com. In this case no session link is printed to the console.

Comment: I have `require('nodetime').profile()`, debug says timekit and v8tools is missing, but they should be installed together within nodetime :s

Comment: Do you have somewhere `nodetime: requesting session from server` in debug output? Is there still no link? i.e. `Nodetime: profiler console for this instance is at https://nodetime.com/xxxxxxxxx`

Comment: i followed your guide from the link you provided below, nodetime seems successfully installed, `nodetime@0.4.5 node_modules\nodetime
├── request@2.10.0
├── timekit@0.1.9 (bindings@1.0.0)
└── v8tools@0.1.1 (bindings@1.0.0)` but still getting no link... i get this in debug `nodetime: requesting session from server
nodetime error: { [Error: Cannot find module 'v8tools']`

Comment: Normally if nodetime cannot connect to server you should see an error when in debug mode, e.g connection timeout, etc. Can you connect to https://nodetime.com at all from a node process (you could try it out with `request` module)? Could you also post the complete debug output or send it to an email address, which you can find at nodetime.com (in footer)

Answer (score 1):

Python required to successful build of `nodetime`. Install `python` first. Then reinstall `nodetime`.

Comment: I don't know what is the python, the only thing i know is it is not a node module. Would be nice if you can provide a link about the python.

Comment: Python is a programming language like others (php/perl/ruby). It uses for build some parts of nodetime. You need to install it. If you use ubuntu just execute `sudo apt-get install python`.

Comment: On Windows you just download from http://www.python.org/getit/ and install it. Here is how it worked for me on windows http://nodetime.com/blog/nodetime-on-windows

Comment: Then you must set up the PYTHON env var, which for some reason the installer does not do itself.